# Quitar elementos de un diccionario

Tags: python

este diccionario es la respuesta que obtengo de un request:

```
{
   "notFoundIds":"None",
   "items":[
      {
         "id":"YGFyazov",
         "email":[
            "john@gmail.com"
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Quisiera quitar los elementos "notFoundIds", "items" para que el dicionario quede asi:

```
{
 "id":"YGFyazov",
 "email":[
    "john@gmail.com"
 ]
}
```

El siguiente es mi codigo:

```
for valor in respuesta.values():
  salida = valor
print(salida)
```

Pero la salida que obtengo es una lista como esta:

```
[
    {
     "id":"YGFyazov",
     "email":[
        "john@gmail.com"
     ]
    }
]
```

Utilizo Python 3.6
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad tu no quieres *quitar items de un diccionario* y tampoco es un tema de *quitar los corchetes* (o las llaves).

Lo que tiene el primer diccionario, son los elementos `notFoundIds` e `Items`. `Items`, a su vez, es una lista de diccionarios, y lo que tu quieres es el primer elemento de dicha lista.

Una vez comprendes la estructura, obtener el elemento que quieres debiera resultar algo trivial, por ejemplo:

```
respuesta = {
   "notFoundIds":"None",
   "items":[
      {
         "id":"YGFyazov",
         "email":[
            "john@gmail.com"
         ]
      }
   ]
}

solucion = respuesta["items"][0];

print(solucion)
```

ìmprime:

```
{'id': 'YGFyazov', 'email': ['john@gmail.com']}
```

Comment: muchas gracias por la explicacion. Lo he comprendido. Gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Edicion:

En realidad lo que quieres es tomar el valor de items, como es una lista solo debes acceder a la lista y tomar el primer elemento:

```
d["items"][0]
```

Respuesta orignal:

Suponiendo que tu variable se llame `d` podes eliminar una entrada del diccionario usando

```
del d["notFoundIds"]
```

Comment: gracias.   Lo que necesito es quitar los corchetes del principio y fin.  ```[{'id': 'YGFyazov', 'email': ['john@gmail.com']}] ```  para que quede asi: ```{'id': 'YGFyazov', 'email': ['john@gmail.com']} ```